# Can't reach elements in shadow-root with Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, shadow-root

I'm having some issues to reach elements in a dropdown list with selenium.

I have a list with values that have to be insert in "Business Group" dropdown list, but the elements are in **shadow-root**, so I can't reach any of then.

The values that I have to select are in the tags **kat-option**

I tried almost all elements in the shadow-root , used find_elements and find_element, but I always get the same error: InvalidArgumentException:
Message: invalid argument: invalid locator (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.127)

type(shadow_root1) -- output: selenium.webdriver.remote.shadowroot.ShadowRoot

My code:

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root

root1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#businessGroupKat')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
#type(shadow_root1)
shadow_root1.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')
```

[shadowroot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ju1f.png)

[shadowroot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpPyt.png)

[shadowroot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BULlQ.png)

Comment: Hello @Lucas, Please do not post/share screenshots. Would be nice if you can share the HTML in code view so that others can help you better.

Comment: I think this is returning a dict currently try using .querySelector() within the execute_script.

Comment: Pls post the url

Comment: @LucasOuverney Is shadow-root a HTML element? if it is a script and not an element that you can see and click - Selenium won't be able to find it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
from pyshadow.main import Shadow

shadow = Shadow(driver)
elemento = shadow.find_element('#businessGroupKat')
value = "BR Baby"
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])",elemento, value)
```